# How to parse json value (Javascript Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-core

I need to check the status of BranchName every 10 seconds
Need to get "BranchName, status" value,But the result is not smooth.
I'm not familiar with parsing json of javascript.
How can i do?
Thank you!

get "BranchName, status" value, like this:

```
BranchNameA    
1
BranchNameB
1
```

The get request returns value(json) like this:

```
[
   {
      "BranchNameA":{
         "branchＮumber":"X20001",
         "companyId":"64400001",
         "shopName":"BOLLYTEST",
         "status":"1",
         "statusText":"Online",
         "statusMessage":"bbbb",
         "errorMessage":"",
         "connectTime":"xxxxxx",
         "disconnectTime":"",
         "CheckModel":{

         }
      }
   },
   {
      "BranchNameB":{
         "branchＮumber":"X20001",
         "companyId":"64400001",
         "shopName":"BOLLYTEST",
         "status":"1",
         "statusText":"Online",
         "statusMessage":"bbb",
         "errorMessage":"",
         "connectTime":"xxxxxx",
         "disconnectTime":"",
         "CheckModel":{

         }
      }
   }
]
```

code:

```
<script>
getApi()

function getApi() {

setTimeout(getApi, 10 * 1000);

        $.ajax({
            url: "(api)",
            type: "Get",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                let user = JSON.parse(data);

                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.fields.length; i++) {
                    var Status= jsonData.fields[i];
                    console.log(counter.status);                   
                }
            }
        })
}

</script>
```

Comment: By smooth you mean response time? The time taken for the javascript is negligbile, unless you have huge array of data incoming. You can try writing a server api that just sends the status instead of all the other fields. That will speed up the process a bit.

Comment: The api is obtained by the other party and can only perform parsing operations.

Comment: Ten seconds is just a regular check

Comment: What do you mean by result is not smooth?

Comment: I'm not familiar with parsing json and cannot get the value of "BranchName, status"

Comment: In javascript, you can directly use jsonData.status or jsonData.BranchName if the object contains those fields.

Comment: This will solve:
success: function (data) {
                 
                    var jsonData = apiData;
                    console.log(jsonData);
                    for (i in jsonData)
                    {
                        data = jsonData[i];
                        keys = Object.keys(data);
                        console.log(keys[0]);
                        console.log(data[keys[0]].status);
                    }
                    
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve:

success: function (data) {

```
                var jsonData = apiData;
                console.log(jsonData);
                for (i in jsonData)
                {
                    data = jsonData[i];
                    keys = Object.keys(data);
                    console.log(keys[0]);
                    console.log(data[keys[0]].status);
                }

            }
```